# How should I deal with adware in chrome on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, malware, chrome, ubuntu

I use chrome (but also have firefox) on ubuntu 14.04 32-bit. Recently I started getting popups from 'softwareupdaterlp.com'. I had the sense to realize it was not legitimate and I didn't click install or anything, but I'm worried it might cause problems on my system.

In an attempt to fix the problem I reset all settings on chrome and restarted my computer. My question is - was that an appropriate reaction? Do I need to go further and install AV software/take additional steps or am I ok?

Answer (score 2):

chrome://extensions/

Type this link to your address bar and press enter. These are the extensions of your Google Chrome Browser.

Search for a malicious extension that could be responsible of these popups.
By clicking the trash icon you can easily remove an extension.

Removing extensions do not harm your browser or computer. For being sure you can remove all extensions one by one.

Answer (score 0):

is best to install adware removal software, to have antivirus activated and to stop downloading from untrusted sources

dont know what works on linux but for windows there is a program, free called timefreeze, or paid deepfreeze ( works better from my perspective given the way it approaches the task)

would be helpfull to use it to test software and configurations

as AV sofware is not always 100% , manual removal is the best solution 
you can search files using "everything" or inside files using "file seek"

also it helps to identify files created at the moment( date and time ) of infection , but not always

some infections can be so advanced that the only solution is to save important files to another drive, scan it just to be sure, then reinstall your OS and freeze it